# How can I get a list of all WLANs my computer can see with Python?

Tags: python, wifi

I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import NetworkManager


def get_ssids():
    ssids = []
    for x in NetworkManager.Settings.ListConnections():
        conn = x.GetSettings()
        if '802-11-wireless' in conn and 'ssid' in conn['802-11-wireless']:
            ssids.append(conn['802-11-wireless']['ssid'])
            logging.info(conn)
    return ssids


def main():
    print("Found the following SSIDs:")
    for ssid in get_ssids():
        print("* %s" % ssid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But that shows the SSIDs of all networks I was connected to, not of the networks I currently see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of said library here :-)

```
import NetworkManager

for dev in NetworkManager.NetworkManager.GetDevices():
    if dev.DeviceType != NetworkManager.NM_DEVICE_TYPE_WIFI:
        continue
    for ap in dev.SpecificDevice().GetAccessPoints():
        print ap.Ssid
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! What is the reason for the double `NetworkManager.NetworkManager.GetDevices()` instead of `NetworkManager.GetDevices()`?

Comment: The first one is the library, the second one the `NetworkManager` object.